# MySQL Count parent and childs

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a query in order to get how many users `Users` with how many `Documents`, the result I'm expecting is this one

```
Users     Documents
297       0
5         1
10        3
16        8
```

So I can see my user's activity, and see why there are so many Users without Documents uploaded in another proccess.

I've tried this query

```
SELECT COUNT(u.id) AS Users, COUNT(d.id) AS Documents
FROM user u
INNER JOIN document d ON u.id = d.user_id
GROUP BY u.id
```

The result I'm getting is something like this

```
Users     Documents
1         2
1         1
1         0
1         1
1         1
...
```

Instead of getting the total of users and documents, it gives me the total of documents for each user...

I'm sure this can be done easily, it's a simple query, but I'm totally blocked today.

Tables structure are theese

**USER**
`id, username, password, email`

**DOCUMENT**
`id, title, body, user_id, created_at, updated_at`

Relations are `document.user_id` to `user.id`, nothing complex.

Comment: What is the source for your expected result.

Comment: You mean table structure for both User and Document?

Comment: With the result you meen something like: 297 users have 0 documents, 5 users have 1 documents .... Right?

Comment: Yeah that's what I want.

Comment: table structure and sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**<kbd>sqlfiddle</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33e250/3)

```
select count(t.userId) Users, t.numberOfDocs Documents from (
  select u.id userId, count(d.id) numberOfDocs
  from user u 
  left join document d on d.user_id = u.id
  group by u.id ) as t
group by t.numberOfDocs
-- order by users or number of documents (Depends on your requirements)
;
```

see demo here: [**<kbd>sqlfiddle</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33e250/3)

Comment: That is working with some tweaks, but I get something weird, I've tried with 3000 users and 3000 documents, just 1 user have 2 documents, the rest have 1, so results should be "2999 - 1" and "1 - 2", but it says "2998 -1" and "1 - 2" , doing a `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)` to `Documents` table, says 2999 so... Dunno

Comment: I just added the full query, see sqlfiddle.

Comment: Okay stupid me, I was doing an INNER JOIN that's why I got 2998 instead 2999, because there was 1 user with 0 documents :P Thanks!ç